# How to create custom tableview using scrollview in ios

Tags: ios, data-structures

I want to create a custom table view without using UITableview which is provided by iOS. How can I make it using a scroll view and other classes?
Which data structure I need to use for the reusability concept of a table view.

Comment: What do you plan to use it for? There are free components like https://github.com/malcommac/ScrollingStackContainer roysharon@gmail.com https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka that may be better than writing your own,

Comment: I just want to know the internal implementation of uitableview so that i can create my custom view using the same concept.

Comment: What does your view needs to do? What makes UITableView a bad fit for it?

Comment: @Yonat UITableview is best and fulfills all the requirements. That's why I want to know the internal implementation.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use **stackView inside scrollView** and based upon your dataSource collection you will dynamically add views in stackView. Thats is all you need to create basic tableview.

Comment: How to reuse the view inside stack view?

Comment: You, for example, can add UIView with xib file in project  and create xib instances like that

    class func instanceFromNib() -> EditProfileView {
        return UINib(nibName: "EditProfileView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! EditProfileView
    }

Comment: As its a class method you can call it view's owner class reference directly.

You you can reuse it with datasource array, in tableView you had to register UITableViewCell with tableView and in there you have to just get UIView's xib instances.

Comment: for reusability part, you have to use optional views and when ever any view goes out of the screen bounds you have to set it to nil and in in the same way before coming into screen bounds you to set view's reference again.

Answer (score 0):

Well UITableView is also subclass of UIScrollView, but with alot of reusability.To acheive something like that you will have to do the following steps:

1. Create a xib with your cell design.
2. Put a stackview inside your ScrollView.
3. Prepare a datasource for your list & set unique id's with every record.
4. This id will help you in further tacking a specific cell.
5. Run a loop on your datasource and add xib to stackview.
6. Using scrollview delegate functions add/remove all those xib's which are getting out/In of the scrollview contentInset(visible area).
7. Also you can add tapGesture on each xib to handle 'didSelect' logic.

But instead of doing this hectic thing ourselves a UITableView is like a diamond for us.

Comment: If I run a loop on Datasource then where is the concept of reusability?

Comment: its for the first population of data or even better if you populate the first data also throught the scrollveiw delegates func's

Comment: @shivi_shub I guess you would need to calculate how many of your cells fit on the screen and initialize views for those ones plus a few that are off screen (for smoother scrolling). Then as you're scrolling you would probably have to detect which cells are not on the screen anymore to then re-use those views for cells that will appear.

Comment: Exactly, you would need to do the calculations according to your view height & the content height of the scrollview.